# Selecting distinct value from table1 and table2 and then inserting those in table3

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the statement which I am using.

```
insert into Course_Data (Branch, CC, C_Title, Sem, Credits) 
values 
(select distinct from (select * from Course_Data)
 union
(select * from TEMP1) a order by a.CC)
```

I encountered with error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Course_ Data:

```
Branch |  CC  |  C_Title   |   Sem   | Credits 
CS       sub1    Networks      3rd     4:1:1=6
```

Temp:

```
 Branch |   CC   |   C_Title   |   Sem   | Credits
   MCA     sub1     Compuuters     3rd      4:1:1=6 
   CS      sub1     Networks       3rd      4:1:1=6
```

These are 2 tables, So after executing the query, I have to get MCA Branch data into Course_Data table without duplication of CS branch data. i.e 
Course_Data:

```
Branch |    CC    |    C_Title    |   Sem   | Credits 
 CS      sub1          Networks       3rd       4:1:1=6 
 MCA     sub1          Compuuters     3rd       4:1:1=6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An insertion with `SELECT` statement doesn't need the keyword `VALUES`. See synthax [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
So you query will be

```
INSERT INTO Dist_Data (Branch,CC,C_Title,Sem,Credits) 
select * 
from 
(
    select * from Course_Data 
    union 
    select * from TEMP1
)a 
order by a.CC
```

Be careful while using `*` for `SELECT-INSERT` because if the number of column in the source table and destination table doesn't match, it will throw an error. So its better to use like below

```
INSERT INTO Dist_Data (Branch,CC,C_Title,Sem,Credits) 
select * 
from 
(
    select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5 from Course_Data 
    union 
    select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5 from TEMP1
)a 
order by a.COLUMNNAME
```

**EDIT :**

As per your new requirement, you can use `EXCEPT` clause/operator to avoid insertion of duplicate data to your `Course_Data` table. The order of columns should be the same while using `EXCEPT`. More about `EXCEPT` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281634) to view working of `EXCEPT`**

**QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO Course_Data (Branch,CC,C_Title,Sem,Credits) 
select * 
from 
(
    SELECT Branch,CC,C_Title,Sem,Credits FROM TEMP1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Branch,CC,C_Title,Sem,Credits FROM Course_Data
)a 
order by a.COLUMNNAME
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281633) to view result**

Comment: I am really sorry for the delay Sarath. Thank you for the follow up. Your query is working fine. Thanks a lot once again. :)

Comment: Welcome @Parthasarthi B.K